# Absolute center an element with child elements (containing imgs/iframes) while keeping their aspect ratio on resize

Tags: javascript, css, position, centering

I'm wondering how I can tackle these problems I'm facing.

**Demo**
[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/epeqar/1)

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. `.display` and it's content should adapt to the size of the screen. If the viewport width is too narrow (same with viewport height) – `.display`
   should shrink and all enclosed items should keep their ratio.
2. `.display` and all content should be centered, vertically and horizontally.
3. Let vimeo items have the same aspect ratio as the images (vimeo embed forces 16x9 aspect ratio, but I'd like the height of the video
   to be the same as the images and let vimeo add black bars to fill
   out).

And on a side note, as I have absolute positioned divs above the actual content (`.cursor .left` and `.cursor .right`) controlling the vimeo video will prove to be somewhat problematic. Are there any other solutions out there that could potentially work the same way as these divs do but enable interaction with the content underneath?

Here's a site that have absolute dead center and that keeps ratio of the enclosed items when resized, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I could not figure out how they made this happen other than JS is involved.
[Bureau Collective](http://www.bureaucollective.ch/#!/project/66/0)

**HTML**

```
<div class="display">
    <div class="cursor left"></div>
    <div class="cursor right"></div>
    <div class="work-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1080-675-7.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-1080-675-9.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57840967?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=000000" width="1080" height="608" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.display {
    position: relative;
    width: 1080px;
}

.cursor.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 45%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.cursor.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 45%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.work-carousel {
    margin:50px auto 60px;
    padding:0;
}

.work-carousel item {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.work-carousel item.first { 
    display: block 
}
```

Comment: Does display need to enlarge for larger screens?

Comment: @Asad How do you mean? Display should not be larger than 1080x675 which is the true size of the images inside.

Answer (score -1):

I thought I'd never use this technique!

The trick is in the `padding`:

```
.display {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  height:0;
  padding:56.25% 0 0 0;
}
.item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.item > * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsbin.com/epeqar/7/edit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Although, did you notice that if you resize the height of your browser to be  less than 675px (the height of the image), the images doesn't shrink to fit. And .display doesn't seem to be centered vertically? Atleast not in Firefox 18.